# Uninstall "Logitech app for bluetooth keyboard" completely on Macbook

Tags: macos

I installed logitch app for bluetooth keyboard months ago.

After I uninstalled it from 'Application', it remind me to update every time I power on.

How to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try:

1. Open Finder > Applications > Double check that the app is not on the list, if it is, delete it.
2. Press Cmd + Alt + Esc > Check if you find any suspect Logitech process running and kill it, then restart the computer
3. Reinstall the software and uninstall it again
4. Reinstall the software and uninstall it with AppZapper (appzapper.com)

Let me know if any of these works.

Comment: Killing a running process does not prevent it from getting relaunched upon reboot.

Comment: i think is better before killing process and after delete the app from the application folder and the related file that you can find with a finder custom search with system files included

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've just removed the application itself from `/Applications`, which means that any background apps installed as part of the package are still on the system. The easiest way to resolve this is to just reinstall the application and the use its uninstall option (assuming there is one).

If this fails

- check in your login items if something related to Logitech gets started automatically
- look into `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons` for anything related to Logitech (probably called `com.logitech.SOMETHING`). Just removing these files will stop the updates, you can also `cat` them in Terminal first and remove the software mentioned in the `ProgramArguments` part first.